# Hide custom UITableViewHeaders which contain same text

Tags: ios, uitableview, uilabel

I have some custom UITableViewHeaders which contain a custom label within.

Label contains some Time events example today, yesterday, 20 may 2014 ...,
but it shows twice or three times the event today example.
i am using an sdk and the only way i think is
if there is already a today text on the UutableviewHeader label, dont show the other today headers.

Can i somehow Hide headers if their Label.text is same.
example if the Label.text is different show else hide or dont create at all
so 
if previous header label is same as last header label dont show last if different show header.

Thank you very much.

Comment: You should explain it more clearly. If you want header not to be shown just make the header height 0.00001. - (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return 0.00001;
}

Comment: the question is not clear.

Comment: @ Vineesh TP
i will reformulate question ty

Answer (score 0):

There are may be so many ways but I like to, *(I just put my logic here change it as per your need)*

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    if ([myLabel.text isEqualToString:myLabel.text]) { /// set your logic here
        return 0; /// or whatever 
    } else {
        // whatever height you need to set.
    }
}
```